# How do I add a ramdisk to XP Embedded

Tags: windows-xp, ramdisk, windows-xp-embedded

I'm going to run a program that operates through some temporary files on a Windows XP Embedded machine, and want to spare the compact flash device.  It came with a compact flash image already set up by the manufacturer, so I don't have the target designer tools.  I tried [a set of instructions for XP ramdisk](http://www.picobay.com/projects/2006/06/how-to-make-windows-xp-ram-disk-drive.html), but it was rejected by the XP Embedded hardware wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an unsupported product, AR RAM Disk, that appears to work.

http://www.arsoft-online.com/